# how to make an image zoom when you click a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am doing a school project and because of that, I am restricted to html, css and javascript for a website that I have to make. I am currently making a landing page and have a button that takes the user to another page. I want to make it so when the button is clicked, it zooms on the background image and then takes the user to another page. Here is my code so far:

CSS and then HTML

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #926239;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/cartoon-cave-with-stalactites_29190-1074.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#showcase .button {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #10B589;
  border: #10B589 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#showcase .button:hover {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  animation: wiggle 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section-a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-c {
  display: flex;
}

#section-c div {
  padding: 20px;
}

#section-c .box-1,
#section-c .box-3 {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
}

#section-c .box-2 {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  12% { transform: scale(0.4,  0.65); }
  13% { transform: scale(0.43, 0.67); }
  14% { transform: scale(0.5,  0.76); }
  25% { transform: scale(0.8,  1.3);  }
  37% { transform: scale(0.9,  0.95); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.1,  0.8);  }
  62% { transform: scale(0.9,  1);    }
  75% { transform: scale(0.7,  1.2);  }
  87% { transform: scale(0.8,  1.1);  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <header id="showcase">
    <a href="insertname.html" class="button">Enter The Cave</a>
  </header>
  <body>
  </body>
</head>
<link href="ISTwebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</html>
```

I've tried a lot of other questions on the internet, could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of an animated background zoom with a smooth loss of visibility. Added dynamic class `background_size`. Notice the line in the js code: `document.location.href = "your_link";` Instead of `your_link`, you need to insert your link.

```js
let button_a = document.querySelector('.button');
let background_picture = document.querySelector('#showcase');

button_a.onclick = function(){
  background_picture.classList.add('background_size');
  button_a.classList.add('smooth_button');
  document.location.href = "your_link";
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #926239;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/cartoon-cave-with-stalactites_29190-1074.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.background_size {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 0!important;
}

.smooth_button {
  opacity: 0!important;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#showcase .button {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #10B589;
  border: #10B589 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

#showcase .button:hover {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  animation: wiggle 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section-a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-c {
  display: flex;
}

#section-c div {
  padding: 20px;
}

#section-c .box-1,
#section-c .box-3 {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
}

#section-c .box-2 {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  12% { transform: scale(0.4,  0.65); }
  13% { transform: scale(0.43, 0.67); }
  14% { transform: scale(0.5,  0.76); }
  25% { transform: scale(0.8,  1.3);  }
  37% { transform: scale(0.9,  0.95); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.1,  0.8);  }
  62% { transform: scale(0.9,  1);    }
  75% { transform: scale(0.7,  1.2);  }
  87% { transform: scale(0.8,  1.1);  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <header id="showcase">
    <a class="button">Enter The Cave</a>
  </header>
  <body>
  </body>
</head>
<link href="ISTwebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to make the button disappear when it is zooming

Comment: Yes. Now I will redo my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will mark your answer as the correct one

Comment: also what do you mean by "your_link"?

Comment: In your question, you wrote that there will be a transition to another page. Instead of `your_link` you will need to insert a real link. here - `document.location.href = "your_link";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219715/discussion-between-sergey-kuznetsov-and-aditya-bavigadda).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign the `a`'s href after few second the click event and zooming of the background is happened like the following in my code

```js
btn.onclick = () => {
  showcase.style.transition = "1.5s";
  showcase.style.transform = "scale(1.3)";
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.assign("insertname.html");
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #926239;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/cartoon-cave-with-stalactites_29190-1074.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#showcase .button {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #10B589;
  border: #10B589 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#showcase .button:hover {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  animation: wiggle 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section-a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-c {
  display: flex;
}

#section-c div {
  padding: 20px;
}

#section-c .box-1,
#section-c .box-3 {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
}

#section-c .box-2 {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  12% {
    transform: scale(0.4, 0.65);
  }
  13% {
    transform: scale(0.43, 0.67);
  }
  14% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.76);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1.3);
  }
  37% {
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.95);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 0.8);
  }
  62% {
    transform: scale(0.9, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(0.7, 1.2);
  }
  87% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="showcase">
  <a class="button" id="btn">Enter The Cave</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I fixed up your animation CSS...

```
@keyframes wiggle {
  0% { transform: scale(1.2,  1.2); }
  15% { transform: scale(1.3, 1.3); }
  30% { transform: scale(1.4, 1.4); }
  45% { transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); }
  60% { transform: scale(1.6, 1.6); }
  75% { transform: scale(1.7, 1.7); }
  90% { transform: scale(1.8, 1.8); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.9,1.9); }
}
```

And second I added JS to your button's onclick...

```
<a href="insertname.html" class="button" onclick="event.preventDefault(); showcase.style.animation='wiggle 3s linear 0s infinite normal none'; setTimeout(function(){document.location=this.href;},2000);">Enter The Cave</a>
```

Inside the onclick you'll find...

1. event.preventDefault();  // Stop the anchor from navigating
2. showcase.style.animation='wiggle 3s linear 0s infinite normal none';  // Add the animating CSS to the image
3. setTimeout(function(){document.location=this.href;},2000);  // After a 2 second delay change the page to the desired href.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another child element, and add a script to scale it up a bit producing a zoom effect before going to another page.

CSS (ISTwebsite.css):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Brush Script MT;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #926239;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner-showcase {
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/cartoon-cave-with-stalactites_29190-1074.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.inner-showcase h1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.inner-showcase p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.inner-showcase .button {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #10B589;
  border: #10B589 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.inner-showcase .button:hover {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  animation: wiggle 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section-a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #10B589;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-c {
  display: flex;
}

#section-c div {
  padding: 20px;
}

#section-c .box-1,
#section-c .box-3 {
  background: #10B589;
  color: #fff;
}

#section-c .box-2 {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

@keyframes wiggle {
  12% {
    transform: scale(0.4, 0.65);
  }

  13% {
    transform: scale(0.43, 0.67);
  }

  14% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.76);
  }

  25% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1.3);
  }

  37% {
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.95);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1, 0.8);
  }

  62% {
    transform: scale(0.9, 1);
  }

  75% {
    transform: scale(0.7, 1.2);
  }

  87% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 1.1);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="ISTwebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header id="showcase">
      <div class="inner-showcase">
        <a href="insertname.html" class="button myLink">Enter The Cave</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script>
      document.querySelector('.myLink').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector('.inner-showcase').style = 'transform: scale(1.2)';
        setTimeout(() => location.href = this.href, 1000);
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: You should move your `<header />` element inside your `<body />` and not inside the `<head />` element.

Answer (score 0):

I put my little Library in there too. Look under `// library above - magic under here`:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, responseType = 'json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, x.response);
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = function(url, send, success, responseType ='json', context = null){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, x.response);
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      let s;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        fd.append(k, s);
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = function(node, className){
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// library above - magic under here
const stage = I('stage'), enter = I('enter');
enter.onclick = function(){
  aC(this, 'dis'); aC(stage, 'cave');
  setTimeout(()=>{
    location = 'insertname.html';
  }, 520);
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; color:#000; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
body,html,.main,#stage{
  width:100vw; height:100vh;
}
.hid{
  display:none;
}
.dis{
  opacity:0; transition:opacity 0.1s;
}
#stage{
  display:flex; background:center / cover url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/cartoon-cave-with-stalactites_29190-1074.jpg'); align-items:center; justify-content:center;
}
#stage.cave{
  transform:scale(5); transition:transform 0.5s;
}
#enter{
  background:transparent; color: #10B589; font:25px 'Brush Script MT', cursive; padding:15px 25px; border:#10B589 1px solid; border-radius:10px; margin-top:20px; cursor:pointer;
}
#enter:hover{
  background:#10B589; color:#fff; animation:wiggle 1s;
}
@keyframes wiggle {
  12% { transform: scale(0.4,  0.65); }
  13% { transform: scale(0.43, 0.67); }
  14% { transform: scale(0.5,  0.76); }
  25% { transform: scale(0.8,  1.3); }
  37% { transform: scale(0.9,  0.95); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.1,  0.8); }
  62% { transform: scale(0.9,  1); }
  75% { transform: scale(0.7,  1.2); }
  87% { transform: scale(0.8,  1.1); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='stage'>
      <input id='enter' type='button' value='Enter the Cave' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```